# Sonarqube web UI is too slow

Tags: sonarqube

I'm having trouble with the Sonar web interface. 
All pages takes between 1 and 10 seconds to load.
I was wondering if Sonar was just always this slow, so I've tried the Nemo demo page and it runs fine. So there really is a problem on my installation.
Can you give me hints about where to look?

Thx

Here are the informations of my current installation :

```
SonarQube Info
Version 3.7
Database MySQL 5.5.29-29.4-log
Database Driver MySQL-AB JDBC Driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.24 ( Revision:${bzr.revision-id} )
Database Driver Class -
Database Dialect (Hibernate) mysql (org.sonar.core.persistence.dialect.MySql$MySqlWithDecimalDialect)
Hibernate Default Schema -

System Info
System date Thu Sep 19 17:28:45 CEST 2013
JVM Vendor  Oracle Corporation
JVM Name    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM Version 23.7-b01
Java Version    1.7.0_17-b02
Java Home   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre
JIT Compiler    -
Application Server Container    jetty/7.6.11.v20130520
User TimeZone   Europe/Paris
OS  Linux / amd64 / 3.2.0-51-generic
Processors  16
System Classpath    ../../lib/jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-security-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-io-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-xml-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:../../lib/jetty-continuation-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/jetty-http-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-3.7.jar:../../lib/jetty-servlet-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../:../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:../../extensions/jdbc-driver/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql/jtds-1.2.7.jar
Boot Classpath  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/classes
Library Path    ./lib

Java VM Statistics
Total Memory    600 MB
Free Memory 335 MB
Max Memory  1908 MB
Heap    init = 536870912(524288K) used = 265024384(258812K) committed = 600899584(586816K) max = 1908932608(1864192K)
Non Heap    init = 24313856(23744K) used = 72589168(70887K) committed = 72876032(71168K)     max = 184549376(180224K)
System Load Average (last minute)   92.0%
Loaded Classes (currently/total/unloaded)   12685 / 12685 / 0
Start Time  2013-09-19T17:21:27.879+0200
Threads (total/peak/daemon) 17 / 17 / 8

System Properties
SONAR_HOME  /opt/sonar
awt.toolkit sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
file.encoding   ANSI_X3.4-1968
file.encoding.pkg   sun.io
file.separator  /
java.awt.graphicsenv    sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.headless   true
java.awt.printerjob sun.print.PSPrinterJob
java.class.path ../../lib/jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-security-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-io-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-xml-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:../../lib/jetty-continuation-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/jetty-http-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../lib/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-3.7.jar:../../lib/jetty-servlet-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:../../:../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:../../extensions/jdbc-driver/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql/jtds-1.2.7.jar
java.class.version  51.0
java.endorsed.dirs  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
java.home   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre
java.io.tmpdir  /tmp
java.library.path   ./lib
java.runtime.name   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version    1.7.0_17-b02
java.specification.name Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor   Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version  1.7
java.vendor Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version    1.7.0_17
java.vm.info    mixed mode
java.vm.name    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name  Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor    Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version   1.7
java.vm.vendor  Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version 23.7-b01
jruby.management.enabled    true
line.separator  
os.arch amd64
os.name Linux
os.version  3.2.0-51-generic
path.separator  :
sun.arch.data.model 64
sun.boot.class.path /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/classes
sun.boot.library.path   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-1.7.0.17/jre/lib/amd64
sun.cpu.endian  little
sun.cpu.isalist 
sun.io.unicode.encoding UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command    org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp     org.sonar.application.StartServer
sun.java.launcher   SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding    ANSI_X3.4-1968
sun.management.compiler HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level  unknown
user.country    US
user.dir    /opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64
user.home   /opt/sonar
user.language   en
user.name   sonar
user.timezone   Europe/Paris
wrapper.cpu.timeout 10
wrapper.java.pid    16603
wrapper.jvm.port.max    31999
wrapper.jvm.port.min    31000
wrapper.jvmid   1
wrapper.key Kgip78X4v9wJAWIQ
wrapper.native_library  wrapper
wrapper.pid 16601
wrapper.port    32000
wrapper.service TRUE
wrapper.version 3.2.3
```

Comment: This is certainly not a programming problem. Also, debugging entire third-party apps is not really feasible for SO. SonarQube support would know better.

Comment: Sonar was never really fast to work with. Ten seconds is a lot but depending on your hardware even that can be normal. What are your hardware specs?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube web interface should display pretty fast. Did you follow the recommendation at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing#Installing-SonarQubePlatformOverview?

Comment: Yes, every step. MySQL is on a (powerfull) dedicated server. I've updated the wrapper.conf according to "tuning the web server". The web server is on an internal network with no internet access (could this be a problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install SaonrQube in another directory, with default H2 embedded db and no project analysis, and tell us if the issue still occurs ?

Comment: Yes. Just to be sure I've installed from the last .zip found on SonarQube site, in a fresh user account. Still got the problem. It took 25sec to display /rules_configuration/index/2 (quality profiles>java>sonar way)

Comment: on the home page (dashboards), when hiting the reload button, it takes  constently more than 2 sec.

Comment: What if you install SonarQube (embedded H2 database, standalone mode) on you laptop? Same issue?

Comment: Quicker on another server, but there seems to be no difference between them (HW or SW). I'll investigate this lead.

Comment: @Higgins : Hi, do you have some news of your investigations ? I have a similar problem on profiles management but with VM Linux/Oracle : [sonarqube-web-ui-profiles-management-is-slow-with-oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157472/sonarqube-web-ui-profiles-management-is-slow-with-oracle). Perhaps information in this thread could help to compare / reproduce. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a difference in response times as a function of the browser. Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.101 m) was slower and IE (Version 9.0.8112.16421) was faster. Both browsers run under Windows 7 SP1. I was wondering if anyone else saw the same results?
Thanks, Charlie