# Does sonarqube 5.1 support ARM?

Tags: linux, sonarqube, synology

I'm trying to install sonarqube in a Synology Diskstation DS112j with an ARM Processor.

In `sonarqube-5.1/bin` folder there's only batch files for linux-x86-32/64 bits so I can't start sonarqube due to this error

```
/var/services/sonarqube-5.1/bin/linux-x86-32/./wrapper: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
Failed to start SonarQube.
```

Is there any sonar.sh for ARM or any workaround to install sonarqube in an ARM diskstation?

Answer (score 3):

SonarQube does not officialy support ARM processors, that's why there's no `sonar.sh` script for ARM.

What's more, I know some guys tried to make it work, but they failed.

- [Thread 1](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-on-Raspberry-Pi-with-OpenJDK-arm-CPU-and-tomcat-7-td5004686.html)
- [Thread 2](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Unexpected-stack-trace-using-ARM-based-linux-td5008314.html)

Still, you can try again and write a simple script so start SQ:

```
#! /bin/sh
java -jar lib/sonar-application-5.1.jar
```

Just put this script in the SQ intallation root directory, run it, et voilà!

*(if SonarQube starts but has other errors, please open another question)*

Answer (score 0):

In the past (cf. [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157472/sonarqube-web-ui-profiles-management-is-slow-with-oracle)), I succeed to run SonarQube v3.7.3 on a Qnap 219 : CPU armv5tel.

Using `linux-x86-32` script, but with a `Java Service Wrapper` lib override : [Linux armel](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp#stable)

I can retry and write more detailed process if not trivial ...

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube Scanner now (3.1) provides a `ANY` release, which supports running in native java installation. The `bin/sonar-scanner` file is a shell script which works just fine.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner